# join clause not showing all results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

this is a very weird issue.
I have 3 tables, all with key relations on agent_id.

Now this query :

```
select DATE_FORMAT(created_on,"%d/%m/%y") as date
from logs
where agent_id = "18"
and log_status="1"
and date_format(created_on,"%m/%y") = "12/12"
group by YEAR(created_on), MONTH(created_on), DAY(created_on) desc
```

Does exactly what it suppoused to, it returns 3 rows of :

```
date
31/12/12
30/12/12
26/12/12
```

However when I join 2 other tables it excludes the date of `31/12/12`. This is the query :

```
select  DATE_FORMAT(l.created_on,"%d/%m/%y") as date
from logs l
join logs_rewards lr on l.id = lr.related_log_id 
join agents a on a.id = l.agent_id 
where l.log_status = "1" 
and DATE_FORMAT(l.created_on,"%m/%y") = '12/12'
AND l.agent_id = '18' 
group by YEAR(l.created_on), MONTH(l.created_on), DAY(l.created_on) desc
```

This returns :

```
date
30/12/12
26/12/12
```

And I can't figure out why that happens. Any help?

I've tried changing `AND l.agent_id = '18'` to `AND a.id = '18'` but same result.

Comment: This is because `logs_rewards`  or `agents` tables not having corresponding data. You have done `INNER JOIN` here. If you do `LEFT JOIN` you will get it.

Comment: Are there associated records for that date in `logs_rewards` and `agents`?  Perhaps you want an outer join?  Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: @Sahal Damn, forgot about that. this was the problem thank you. you can submit as answer and i'll accept yours if you want, or i'll accept gezimi's answer.

Comment: I have given the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because data are not mapped in all the 3 tables.

Below query will work

```
select  DATE_FORMAT(l.created_on,"%d/%m/%y") as date
from logs l
left join logs_rewards lr on l.id = lr.related_log_id 
left join agents a on a.id = l.agent_id 
where l.log_status = "1" 
and DATE_FORMAT(l.created_on,"%m/%y") = '12/12'
AND l.agent_id = '18' 
group by YEAR(l.created_on), MONTH(l.created_on), DAY(l.created_on) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to replace **JOIN** with **LEFT JOIN** to get all results from logs.